# Reading Microsoft Word in order read

Tags: java, apache-poi, inputstream

I am currently implementing an application that reads a Microsoft Word document using Apache POI. As per the API, there exists HWPFDocument class that accepts in an InputStream as part of the constructor.

I would like to read images and tables from the input stream in the order it is received. Although, the API offers to read all the images and all the tables is there any way of either using Apache POI to detect the order. For example, 1 paragraph followed by a table followed by an image. I want to detect the ordering of this input stream to do other things with them. Something like this:

```
while(input stream != null) {
     // read byte if paragraph do something
    // if table do something
}
```

Having a look on Google and the Apache POI, I haven't seen anything like this.

Comment: are you dealing with `.doc`, or `.docx`? doc is a compound ole file, and is basically random binary garbage that mere mortals can't even pretend to TRY and tread, and there's no guaranteed that your document arrives in any kind of useful order. .docx is a zip file, and again, no guarantee as to how things are arranged in the .zip, let alone have it be decompressible and "usable" while the file is incomplete.

Comment: It will be a .docx file. Is there any other solution to this? How does Microsoft Word to PDF work then? I am sure there must be a way to read the entire lot as it is.

Comment: What happens if you try with the Text Extractors that ship as part of Apache POI - does that not show you the text you want in order?

Comment: No, I haven't tried. I am sure it does. However, as I stated in the description above I would like to access everything in order. So, if the image is first or the table is first and so on. Would you have any ideas as to how I can achieve this?